# Where does Helm store installation state?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When you run a `helm install` command, Helm outputs information like the revision of this installation.

Where does Helm store this information? (I assume it's in the cluster somewhere.)

Answer (score 19):

## Depends on configuration

I found the answer in the docs.

> Helm 3 changed the default release information storage to Secrets in the namespace of the release.
> https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#storage-backends

It goes on to say that you can configure it to instead store that state in a `ConfigMap` or in a PostgreSQL database.

So by default, `kubectl get secret --namespace my-namespace` will include an entry like

```
sh.helm.release.v1.st.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      13m
```

And `kubectl describe secret sh.helm.release.v1.st.v1` will output something like

```
Name:         sh.helm.release.v1.st.v1
Namespace:    my-namespace
Labels:       modifiedAt=1613580504
              name=st
              owner=helm
              status=deployed
              version=1
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  helm.sh/release.v1
```

Answer (score 3):

The storage is changed in Helm 3 as follows:

- Releases are stored as Secrets by default (it [could use](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#sql-storage-backend) PostgreSQL).
- Storage is in the namespace of the release.
- Naming is changed to `sh.helm.release.v1.<release_name>.v<revision_version>`.
- The Secret type is set as `helm.sh/release.v1`.

List installed helm Charts:

```
      $ helm ls --all-namespaces
      NAME           NAMESPACE    REVISION    UPDATED   STATUS  CHART     APP VERSION
      chrt-foobar    default      2           2019-10-14 15:18:31.529138228 +0100 IST    deployed    chrt-foobar-0.1.0    1.16.0     
      chrt-test      test         1           2019-10-14 15:20:28.196338611 +0100 IST    deployed    chrt-test-0.1.0      1.16.0
```

List helm releases history

```
    $ kubectl get secret -l "owner=helm" --all-namespaces
    NAMESPACE   NAME                                TYPE                 DATA   AGE
    default     sh.helm.release.v1.chrt-foobar.v1   helm.sh/release.v1   1      3m2s
    default     sh.helm.release.v1.chrt-foobar.v2   helm.sh/release.v1   1      2m40s
    test        sh.helm.release.v1.chrt-test.v1     helm.sh/release.v1   1      43s
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to Helm in Helm2: The **Helm client** `(helm)` and the **Helm server** `(Tiller)` (removed in Helm3).

When we run `helm init` it install the Tiller part on Kubernetes cluster. You can confirm the installation

```
kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system 
#see Tiller running.
```

> Where does Helm store this information? (I assume it's in the cluster somewhere.)
> As for

By default, tiller stores release information in ConfigMaps in the namespace where it is running, the new version also supports SQL storage backend for release information.

[storage-backends](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/install/#storage-backends)

To get release information

```
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system -l "OWNER=TILLER"
```

then check the release info from config map

```
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system -o yaml myapp.v2:
```

[how-helm-uses-configmaps-to-store-data](http://technosophos.com/2017/03/23/how-helm-uses-configmaps-to-store-data.html)

Comment: I'm using Helm 3.4.1. According to the docs, Tiller was removed in version 3 - https://helm.sh/docs/faq/#changes-since-helm-2
`kubectl get configmap -n kube-system -l "OWNER=TILLER"` finds no resources.

Comment: Aha - I found in the answer in the docs - "Helm 3 changed the default release information storage to Secrets in the namespace of the release." - https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#storage-backends